# Taskid in MapReduce

Tags: mapreduce

I am newbie to MapReduce and Java programming. I am trying to get taskid of each map() function. Basically I need to use taskid of each mapper as offset for fetching some data from a common file.

Please help me getting taskid of individual map() task.

Thanks,
Vanamala

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its too late to answer, but you can get the task attempt id and then task id when you set up your map using the Context object. The getTaskAttemptID() does just that for you.